# Paquete "time" y "math" en golang

Tags: date, go, math, count, seed

**Hace unos meses empecè a aprender a programar en Golang** ya que en la uni me lo pidieron pero hay muchas cosas que no entiendo, por favor no me den dislike, necesito ayuda ya que me gusta mucho este tema y quisiera aprender màs.

*Hay cosas que no entiendo sobre el paquete "time" y el paquete "math"*

**rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())**

*"Què quiere decir o què es Seed? Y què funciòn cumple? O què hace time.Now al lado de UnixNano? Què es UnixNano?"*

**Aquì hay un ejemplo de ejercicio que no puedo leer ya que no sè a què se refieren con todo esto, entiendo muy poco de este programa, se los agradezco de antemano. Saludos.**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const max = 10

func main() {
    ganado := false
    var count int
    var input int
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    numToGuess := rand.Intn(max +1)

for i:=0; i<(max/2); i++{
    fmt.Println("adivina")
    fmt.Scan(&input)
    if input == numToGuess{
        count++
        fmt.Println("Adivinado en ",count, "intentos")
        ganado = true
        break
    }
    if input <1 || input > max{
        fmt.Println("fuera de intervalo")
        continue
    }else {
        count++
    }

}
if !ganado{
    fmt.Println("has perdido, el numero era ", numToGuess)
}
```

}

Comment: Tienes profesor aprovecha las horas de tutoría,,,seed es semilla ingles y sirve para generar números aleatorios...creo que una misma semilla produce los mismos números de hay que se use el tiempo para iniciar una secuencia aleatoria y si es en nano-segundos mejor

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar la documentación oficial de Go para sacarte todas las dudas. Una de las mejores cosas de Go es su detallada documentación. https://pkg.go.dev/ aquí ingresas el nombre del paquete y podrás encontrar la documentación oficial de lo que buscas. https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand@go1.19.5#Seed lo mejor que puedes hacer para aprender Go es leer la documentación